# Show that the mapping $f → f~'$ from $C^1([0 , 1])$ to $C([0 , 1])$ is not continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $C^1([0 , 1])$ be the subspace of $C([0 , 1])$ consisting of the functions that have a continuous derivative throughout $[0 , 1]$. Show that the mapping
$\Psi:f → f~'$ from $C^1([0 , 1])$ to $C([0 , 1])$ is not continuous.

**Definitions Used :** $f~'$ denotes the derivative of a function $f$.

$C([0 , 1])$ denotes the set of bounded continuous functions from $([0 , 1])$ to $\mathbb R$ and uses the metric $e(f_1,f_2) = \sup \{ f_1(x) - f_2(x)~|~x \in [0,1]\}$

**Solution attempt:**

If we prove that $\exists ~f_1,f_2 \in C([0 , 1])~|~~\sup |f_1~'(x) - f_2~'~(x)| > \epsilon$ whenever $ \sup|f_1(x) - f_2(x)| < \delta$

$\implies $ we need to find functions $f_1,f_2 \in C([0 , 1])~$ such that $|f_1~'(x) - f_2~'~(x)| > \epsilon$ whenever $|f_1(x) - f_2(x)| < \delta~\forall x \in [0,1]$

Could someone please tell me if I have I proceeded in the right manner?

How do I move next?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You have the right idea.  Now, you just need to think of an example that works for a fixed $\epsilon$ and arbitrarily small $\delta$.

Comment: Try functions of the form $f(x)={\sin nx\over n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One classic example that can help you here is the set of functions of the form 
$$
f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + 1/n}
$$
for $n \in \Bbb N$.  Note that the functions $f_n(x)$ form a Cauchy sequence, but their derivatives do not.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the monomials $$f_n(x) = \frac{x^{n^2}}{n}.$$